# jquery mobile 1.1.1 ui-mini

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have just upgraded jquery mobile from 1.1.0 to 1.1.1 and my navbar is messed up now. Googling I've discovered that, in 1.1.1, the .ui-mini class is added by default.
Unfortunately the documentation isn't up to date so I don't know how to get back the "classic" style for my tabs.

I've tried data-mini="false", data-full="true" but it doesn't works.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Navbar with 1.1.1 Styles:

[image]

Seems to be working fine except for the extra margins around the buttons - http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/Mc3be/

The `.ui-mini` class only adds some margin... you can get rid of that:

HTML:

```
<div id="myNavBar" data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="a.html">One</a></li>
       <li><a href="b.html">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

CSS:

```
#myNavBar.ui-mini {
    margin: 0 0;
}
```

Navbar with .ui-mini margin removed:

[image]

Comment: Tabs are smaller this way (and that's correct). I don't want to override the .ui-mini style to match the correct height because I used it on other elements.

Comment: you can just override .ui-mini for your navbar only.